# How do i extract a changing substring that follows a constant string in an excl cell

Tags: excel-formula, substring, extract

I have 1000s of cells that show something like the following:

```
{'gender': 'Female', 'nationality': 'USA', 'document_type': 'national_identity_card', 'date_of_expiry': '2001-03-15', 'issuing_country': 'USA'}
```

The remaining cells could have some info or not, but I'm trying to extract 'national_identity_card' that occurs after 'document_type'. Now document type could be anything, passport, driving license etc, but the format is like the above.

Thank you for your time.

These are linked to individual IDs from which I could do a vlookup or an index match, but I don't know how to extract a specific string

What kind of a formula could help me in extracting such information?

I want to be able to create a column with a heading 'document_type' with each row being populated with 'national_identity_card', 'passport' etc linked to each ID on the row

Comment: Parsing JSON using an excel formula. I am not envious :(

Comment: you can look here for some vba that might help: http://excelerator.solutions/2017/08/16/import-json-to-excel-using-vba/

Comment: THanks guys, the excelerator link would work if i have JSON in the first place. Would it work with already populated 'excel file' that has this JSON string

Comment: That code refers to a string in a cell not JSON itself.  So yes it would do that.

Answer (score 0):

This formula does the job:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("document_type",A1)+17,FIND(",",A1,FIND("document_type",A1))-(FIND("document_type",A1)+17+1))
```

A1 is where your data is and you can tweak the 17s to include or exclude the ' marks.

Essentialy it finds the position of "document_type" and the position of the next comma and uses them to extract a substring containing the value.